# How do you send GPS coordinates from one android phone to another?

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I am writing a android application that will hopefully let me and a few friends see where each other are. It requires each phone to send the gps coordinates to each other. Is there anyway to do that in the SDK / Java? Each device that will be included will be hard coded and can't be changed. Thanks for any help I can get!

Comment: Cool project, but have you tried Google latitude?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special trick to passing around GPS coordinates.  You'll have to used standard ways like setting up a central server to receive and broadcast some coordinates or you could use SMS's to pass the details around automatically.

Comment: The SMS trick is probably the simplest - unlimited SMS is very common those days (at least in UK and US).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to connect to each of the devices directly, you might want to consider having each device store its location on a server somewhere. That has several advantages:

1. The server is easy to find. It's address is known by all the devices.
2. Each device only needs one network connection to get the latest locations of all the other devices. It might not be a big deal for three devices to all connect to each other, but it's a problem for as few as one or two dozen devices.
3. The server is more likely to be reachable.

Using a server doesn't have to be complicated. All you really need to do is let each device post a file to a common directory.